# Find number of JInternalFrame in JdesktopPane

Tags: swing, jframe, jinternalframe, jdesktoppane

i am creating number of JInternalFrame in the JDesktopPane.Is there any way to get the created  JInternalFrame.(Like each loop i.e Getting one by one).

Answer (score 0):

Seriously? All the standard Java classes have a documentation:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JDesktopPane.html#getAllFrames%28%29